# Three types of threads attempting to access critical section

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, semaphore, critical-section

For my application I need to be sure, that in critical session only one type of thread is processing. Number of threads for given type is not specified and could be "large". I've came with simple solution:

```
MutableInt a,b,c;
Semaphore mutex;

void enterA() {
    while (true) {
        mutex.acquire();
        if (b.intValue() == 0 && c.intValue() == 0) {
            a.increase();
            break;
        }
        mutex.release();
    }
}

void exitA() {
    while(true) {
        mutex.acquire();
        a.decrease();
        mutex.release();
    }
}
```

I'm skipping exception handling and B&C part cause its just copy-paste.

It works as expected (possibility of thread starvation is ok), but the generated load is too big. Threads are constantly checking counters. I feel there is another solution but can't think of any example.

Comment: The reason for the high CPU load is that one thread is always able to run. There are no blocking calls in your code except for the mutex.acquire(). So I suppose that one CPU core is constantly at 100%.

Comment: Thx for summarisation however this one I actually know. I'm tring to figure out a way to notify only those threads that are interested for the event.

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell if your solution is a portion of the problem but as it stands I'd recommend moving to `AtomicInteger` which handles all of the incrementing, etc. for you without locking.

If it is more complicated then you should consider using `AtomicReference` with some accumulator class and use `compareAndSet(...)` method to update it atomically.

For example, you could store your 3 integers in a `MutableInts` class and do something like the following:

```
final AtomicReference<MutableInts> reference =
     new AtomicReference<MutableInts>(new MutableInts(0, 0, 0));
...
do {
   MutableInts ints = reference.get();
   // increment the ints properly which should generate a new MutableInts class
   // it should _not_ make changes to `ints` itself
   MutableInts newInts = ints.mutateSomehow(...);
   // this spins in case some other thread updated it before us here
} while (!reference.compareAndSet(ints, newInts));
```

So it seems like you are limited in the calls you can use to accomplish this.   Here are some other alternatives:

- Each thread update their own data and then every so often (or maybe just at the end of processing) synchronize up with a central counters.  Same locks but doing it a *lot* less often.
- Each thread could update per-thread `volatile` counters and a polling thread could read the counters and update the central information.  Not sure if `volatile` is allowed.

Comment: Unfortunately I am made to use just plain semaphores. Actually MutableInt is just a shortcut for Q&A to minimize code complexity... - this class is written by myself

Comment: this is an issue that came over while doing application for my Parallel Processing course